# A Sequence That has No Upper Bound But Does Not Tend To Infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ be a sequence which has no upper bound.

Give an counterexample sequence for the statement
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$$

Any hint?

Comment: $a_n = n$ if $n$ is even, $a_n = 1/n$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: "Converges" is not the same as "it is false that $a_n\to\infty$". A divergent sequence could also diverge to (*hint*, *hint*...)

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space, so every convergent sequence is bounded, and your title is looking for the impossible.

Comment: Sorry, edited title

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know the epsilon-delta definition of $a_n\to\infty$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two examples:
$$(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,\dots)$$
$$(1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,\dots)$$
The first sequence doesn't got to infinity, because it has a subsequence that goes to $0$. Similarly, the second doesn't, because it has a subsequence that goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: I see, forgot that a sequence have a limit iff the subsequences converges to the same limit

Comment: @gbox This also can be seen with the epsilon-delta definition of $a_n\to\infty$ (which is: For every lower bound $M$, there is an index $N$ such that for every $n>N$, $a_n>M$). If you let $M=0$ for either of these, you'll see that they violate the definition.

Comment: or in other words for $n>N$ there are still elements that $a_n<M$.
Thanks

Comment: @gbox Well, $a_n\le M$, but yeah. (Not that it matters much, though — you could just choose a higher $M$.)

Answer (score 2):

How about a sequence that has subsequences with different limits? Can you construct one that fits what you're looking for?